# Spacing between pie slices

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to find a way too

Option 1. Add spacing between the slices

Option 2. Remove the current small white/dead space between the pies:

[image]

Do you know the class or way to do it?

I want it to look like this for option 1:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a chart like this by modifying border options as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      innerSize: '50%',
      borderWidth: 10,
      borderRadius: 10,
      borderColor: 'white',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['Slice 1', 2],
      ['Slice 2', 4],
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kfj1gecv/2/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.borderWidth
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.borderRadius